# Error while getting data from db

Tags: android

I'm trying to get data from my db. I've already 50-60 methods I use for do operations on my db and all of them work good. Today I've created another method... But it doesn't work! Idk maybe it's because I'm using 2 times the same cursor.. Idk... This is the code that generates the mistake:

```
public ArrayList<String> getValueFromTab(String tipoGrafico){

    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = null;
    Cursor data = null;
    String ascissa=null;
    String tabella=null;
    ArrayList<String>dati=new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        sqlDB = openDataBase(SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        data=sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT TABELLA, ASCISSA FROM cpm_analysis WHERE CATEGORIA='"+tipoGrafico+"' AND ABILITATO <>'no'", null);

        if(data.getCount()==0){
            data=null;
        }else{
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                tabella=data.getString(0);
                ascissa=data.getString(1);
            }
            data=null;
        }
        data=sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT"+ascissa+" FROM "+tabella+"", null);

        if(data.getCount()==0){
            data=null;
        }else{
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                dati.add(data.getString(1));
            }
            data=null;
        }
        return dati;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (data != null)
            data.close();
        if (sqlDB != null)
            sqlDB.close();
    }

    return null;

}
```

I'm taking an exception after the first rawquery().

This is another method that works perfectly:

```
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = null;
    Cursor data = null;

    try {
        sqlDB = openDataBase(SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        String[] posizioni=new String[]{"Grafici UL", "Grafici UR", "Grafici DL", "Grafici DR"};
        String[] categorie=new String[posizioni.length];
        String categorieTemp="";
        for(int i=0; i<posizioni.length; i++){
            data=sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT CATEGORIA FROM cpm_analysis WHERE AREA_DISPLAY='"+posizioni[i]+"' AND ABILITATO <> 'no' ", null);
            if(data.getCount()==0){
                data=null;}

            else{   
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                categorieTemp=data.getString(0);
                categorie[i]=categorieTemp;
            }
            data=null;
            }
        }
        return categorie;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (data != null)
            data.close();
        if (sqlDB != null)
            sqlDB.close();
    }

    return null;

}
```

Where is the mistake? Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance

EDIT

please help me >.< I'm going crazy...

RE-EDIT

Ok I resolved it. Idk why but I cant call this method from one activity, so I called it in the Activity before. It didn't open db.. Idk why @_@ Now it works... Ty at all :)

Comment: could you post your logcat for that exception?

Comment: it's very hard to answer your question without error messages and /or stacktraces

Comment: it's a NullPointerException... =_=

Answer (score 2):

Give Proper Spaces between DISTINCT and column name.

```
 data=sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT "+ascissa+" FROM "+tabella+"", null);
```

Comment: yeah this was an error, but I'm taking exception in first query, not in the second. I tried to correct this error and I still get the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The same goes for `data=sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT TABELLA, ASCISSA FROM cpm_analysis WHERE CATEGORIA='"+tipoGrafico+"' AND ABILITATO <>'no'", null);`

This part 
`... AND ABILITATO <>'no'", null);` 
has no proper space afer <> as well.

Comment: Correct it... But it goes in exception at the same line. I've already copied my query and i've executed it directly on db and it works...

Comment: To give you some hints on where it is going wrong, you could try and start logging some information to LogCat. 
I always start to overspecify all steps, to show where stuff can go wrong.  
`/**
lookupWineID(String q) returns an array of ID's based on the name of the wine in string q.  
**/
public String[] lookupWineID(String q) {
 Log.v("lookupWineID", "Started");
 // Open the database
 openDataBase();
 Log.v("lookupWineID", "Database Opened");`

Comment: I wasn't allowed to call this method from the activity i wasu using. So i called it from another activity and it works :) i've written it in my edit